# 16.04.3 - which ist the current kernel and where to get it?

Tags: 16.04, kernel

I have tried several new kernel (4.14, 4.15) from the page
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

**1. Questions: are these kernel from the mainline page safe and will they be patched or is it safer to got back to the original kernel?**

If safer I would like to go back to the latest official kernel for Ubuntu 16.04.3 which should be a 4.4.0x version?

**2. Questions: where can I get this kernel and which one to use?**

If I use

```
   sudo apt-get install linux-image-4
```

and TAB I get several suggestions for 4.4, 4.8, 4.10, 4.13 and even 4.14 kernels

> linux-image-4.14.0-1003-azure-edge
> linux-image-4.14.18-041418-generic
> linux-image-4.14.1-041401-generic
> linux-image-4.14.19-041419-generic

It is a 64-bit system and I need the generic kernel, no low latency needed.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: I have just found the programme "UKUU".
This is an kernel manager and you can install and remove/purge the latest kernels even with a GUI.

Comment: http://www.teejeetech.in/p/ukuu-kernel-upgrade-utility.html